# My MIDI JACK messages are sended from the port buffer AGAIN AND AGAIN

Tags: c++, infinite-loop, midi, jack

these are my specific **Jack MIDI** lines:

```cpp
const char* client_name {"Commander"};
jack_client_t* client {NULL};
jack_port_t* output_port {NULL};
jack_nframes_t local_nframes = {0};

int process(jack_nframes_t nframes, [[maybe_unused]]void* arg) {/*{{{*/
    local_nframes = nframes;
    return 0;
}/*}}}*/

void Keyboard::connect() noexcept{/*{{{*/
    // Open a connection to the JACK server
    client = jack_client_open(client_name, JackNullOption, NULL);
    if (client == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open " << client_name << "client at Keyboard::connect()\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create a MIDI output port
    output_port = jack_port_register(client, "output", JACK_DEFAULT_MIDI_TYPE, JackPortIsOutput, 0);
    if (output_port == NULL) {
        // Failed to create output port
        jack_client_close(client);
        std::cerr << "Failed to open " << client_name << "port at Keyboard::connect()\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Set the process callback function
    jack_set_process_callback(client, process, 0);

    // Activate the client
    if (jack_activate(client) != 0) {
        // Failed to activate client
        jack_port_unregister(client, output_port);
        jack_client_close(client);
        std::cerr << "Failed to activate " << client_name << "client at Keyboard::connect()\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    MIDI = Switch::ON;
}/*}}}*/

void Keyboard::dump_performance(const Performance& _Performance) noexcept/*{{{*/
{
    set_performance_buffer(_Performance); // Pass to the buffer

    // Sleep
    static struct timespec keyboardTimer;
    keyboardTimer.tv_sec = 0;
    keyboardTimer.tv_nsec = 200000000;

    // Change page
    [[maybe_unused]]jack_midi_data_t combiSysEx[7] = {0xF0, 0x42, 0x30, 0x7A, 0x4E, 0x00, 0xF7};
    [[maybe_unused]]jack_midi_data_t timbreSysEx[7] = {0xF0, 0x42, 0x30, 0x7A, 0x4E, 0x01, 0xF7};

    // MIDI Ch = msb[0], lsb[0], pc[0] are the same, only the last digit changes
    [[maybe_unused]]jack_midi_data_t msb[3] = {0xB0, 0x00, 0x3F};
    [[maybe_unused]]jack_midi_data_t lsb[3] = {0xB0, 0x20, 0x00};
    [[maybe_unused]]jack_midi_data_t pc[2] = {0xC0, 0x00};

    // Adjustment
    lsb[2] = performance_buffer.patch.bnk - 65; /*LSB*/
    pc[1] = performance_buffer.patch.num; /*PC*/

    // Retrieve the output port buffer
    void* port_buffer = jack_port_get_buffer(output_port, local_nframes);

    // Clear the port buffer before writing MIDI events
    jack_midi_clear_buffer(port_buffer);

    // Send the MIDI messages to the output port
    if (output_port != nullptr) {
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, combiSysEx,   sizeof(combiSysEx));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, timbreSysEx,  sizeof(timbreSysEx));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, msb,          sizeof(msb));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, lsb,          sizeof(lsb));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, pc,           sizeof(pc));
    }

    // Sleep
    nanosleep(&keyboardTimer, NULL);

    set_scene(performance_buffer.default_scene);
    //dump_scene();
}/*}}}*/

void Keyboard::disconnect() noexcept {/*{{{*/
    // Deactivate, unregister, and close the client
    jack_deactivate(client);
    jack_port_unregister(client, output_port);
    jack_client_close(client);

    // Set MIDI switch to OFF or perform any necessary cleanup
    MIDI = Switch::OFF;
}/*}}}*/
```

When the first `jack_midi_event_write()` function from `Keyboard::dump_performance()` is called, it correctly send the message but **infinite times**. There is no way to stop. Even if i disconnect and reconnect to the other client. **I have to disconnect my client**.

There is no loop anywhere in my program. In fact **the each message is repeated indefinedly and the program continues without problem**. Is like *the port_buffer continues sending all his received messages*.

[My client connected to REAPER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdkjU.jpg)

[REAPER receiving again and again the same messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR0TI.jpg)

How could I solve it?

- Recorded the output of my program into Reaper and notice the brutal looping of the same messages.
- Try to send just one message

Nothing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, it was a misunderstood of the JACK mechanism and the behaviour of the Jack **callback functions**.

The `process()` function is designed to **containt all the data input and output messages**. Also, **it works asynchroniusly** from the execution of the program (runs independently our program workflow), and at last but not least: the output port buffer works as an independent antena that **will send again and again his received messages**. So there are the key conepts.

The solution? **Put all the `jack_midi_event_write()` calls inside the acurate callback functions** and ensure with flags that the messages will be called by jack just once. So the creation of boolean flags that set `true` when we want the action and `false` inside the callback function is a good approach. Also remember, **let's declare this flag variables as `volatile`**

```cpp
// GENERIC MESSAGES{{{
jack_midi_data_t to_combi_SysEx[] {0xF0, 0x42, 0x30, 0x7A, 0x4E, 0x00, 0xF7};
jack_midi_data_t to_timbre_SysEx[]{0xF0, 0x42, 0x30, 0x7A, 0x4E, 0x01, 0xF7};
struct PatchChangeT {
    jack_midi_data_t msb[3] {0xB0, 0x00, 0x3F};
    jack_midi_data_t lsb[3] {0xB0, 0x20, 0x00};
    jack_midi_data_t pc[2]  {0xC0, 0x00};
} PatchChange;/*}}}*/

// Client {{{
const char* client_name {"Commander"};
jack_client_t* client {NULL};
jack_port_t* output_port {NULL};
jack_nframes_t local_nframes = {0};/*}}}*/

// Control{{{
volatile bool should_send_performance {FALSE};/*}}}*/

int process([[maybe_unused]]jack_nframes_t nframes, [[maybe_unused]]void* arg)/*{{{*/
{
    void* port_buffer = jack_port_get_buffer(output_port, nframes);
    jack_midi_clear_buffer(port_buffer);

    if (should_send_performance) {
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, to_combi_SysEx,  sizeof(to_combi_SysEx));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, to_timbre_SysEx, sizeof(to_timbre_SysEx));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, PatchChange.msb, sizeof(PatchChange.msb));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, PatchChange.lsb, sizeof(PatchChange.lsb));
        jack_midi_event_write(port_buffer, 0, PatchChange.pc,  sizeof(PatchChange.pc));

        should_send_performance = false;
    }
    return 0;
}/*}}}*/

void Keyboard::connect() noexcept {/*{{{*/
    // Connect to the JACK server
    if ((client = jack_client_open(client_name, JackNullOption, NULL)) == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to open JACK client " << client_name << " at Keyboard::connect()\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    // Register the process callback
    jack_set_process_callback(client, process, 0);

    // Create the MIDI output port
    if ((output_port = 
            jack_port_register(client, "midi_out", JACK_DEFAULT_MIDI_TYPE, JackPortIsOutput, 0)) == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to register JACK port midi_out at Keyboard::connect()\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    // Activate the client
    if (jack_activate(client)) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to activate JACK client " << client_name << " at Keyboard::connect()\n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    MIDI = Switch::ON;
}
/*}}}*/

void Keyboard::dump_performance(const Performance& _Performance) noexcept {/*{{{*/
    // SET BUFFER
    set_performance_buffer(_Performance); // Pass to the buffer

    // SLEEP
    static struct timespec keyboardTimer;
    keyboardTimer.tv_sec = 0;
    keyboardTimer.tv_nsec = 200000000;

    // ADJUST MESSAGES
    PatchChange.lsb[2] = performance_buffer.patch.bnk - 65;
    PatchChange.pc[1] = performance_buffer.patch.num;

    should_send_performance = true;
}/*}}}*/

void Keyboard::disconnect() noexcept {/*{{{*/
    // Deactivate, unregister, and close the client
    jack_deactivate(client);
    jack_port_unregister(client, output_port);
    jack_client_close(client);

    // Set MIDI switch to OFF or perform any necessary cleanup
    MIDI = Switch::OFF;
}/*}}}*/
```

Thank you very much